# What are the examples of demigod?

Tags: belief

Lord Krishna has talked about demigod in Bhagavad Gita. Can you give me some example of Demigod.
Are Hanuman, Ganesha and Kartikeya demigod ??

Comment: Demi God is term popularized by "ISKCON". No. Hanuman, Ganesha, Kartikeya are not Demigods for their respective devotees. Devas such as Indra, Agni, vayu etc are considered as Gods. English has only one word God for everything. But Sanskrit has many words. There is only Supreme Brahman and different people call Him/Her/It by different names. He need not be Krishna. For  Gaudiya Vaishnavaites, Brahman is Krishna. For Shaivaites Brahman is Shiva. For Traditional vaishnavaites  Brahman is Vishnu.  For Sauryites, Lord Surya is Brahman.

Comment: Lord Ganesha is one of the 5 MOST important Deities in hinduism.Lord Karthikeya is one of the 6 MOST important Deities.