# Is the term "demigod" necessary to translate the name of any entity in Hinduism to English?

Tags: demi-god

In the post [Do the long term actions of Avataras survive the end of the respective Avataras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32672/do-the-long-term-actions-of-avataras-survive-the-end-of-the-respective-avataras/32683?noredirect=1#comment99841_32683)

a user in the comment section says "there are demigods" in Hinduism.

Is this correct?

**Note: this question is not the same as the other question - which asks for the nearest approximation in Hinduism to the Western cultural/religious term "demigod"**

**Google Translate translates demigod to**

**यक्ष (yaksh) in Hindi
உபதேவதை in Tamil (upadevata).**

**If because of "demigod" talk percolating into Hinduism Siva or Durga start getting called yaksh or upadevata, it would do serious harm to Hinduism.**

Comment: Depends on which school of philosophy one subscribes to.

Comment: I have already answered ur Q here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26568/what-word-from-hindu-scripture-translates-to-demi-god @SK

Comment: why not? see all the saints ultimately speak of three stages:the stage where brahmaa is God(known as Brahma-granthi in yoga and tantra) the mulaadhara chakra, vishnu-granthi where Vishnu is the God corresponding to Anaahata chakra and Rudra granthi corresponding to Ajna chakra. The absolute truth is beyond sahasrara chakra. So as the aspirant proceeds, the concept of God changes. As he moves to higher and higher plane, previous Gods become demi-gods. You can read Sadhana-Samara by Brahmarshi Satyadeva published by the Gita Press --i hope they have an english translation:)

Comment: the other question 'What word from Hindu scripture translates to “demi-god”?' is different - that question just asks for a close approximation in Hinduism to what Westerners call a "demi god" @rickross

Comment: @Rickross You can post answer here as well. I don't think duplicate content is an issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What word from Hindu scripture translates to "demi-god"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26568/what-word-from-hindu-scripture-translates-to-demi-god) and [What are the examples of demigod?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11556/5212)

Comment: "Demigod" is not a traditional hindu term- but, given the hierarchies of divine beings in hindu thought, it has been applied by various people variously.

Comment: it's just a matter of definition/semantics. GOD is parabrahmam. DEMI-GODS are devas, reporting to above GOD.

Comment: "DEMI-GODS are devas, reporting to above GOD."  Devas are Devas.  The universe is not a corporation with bosses and subordinates.

Comment: @SK It is a corporation with boss and subordinates. There is only one god "Ekam eva advitiyam Brahma". It is not a socialistic firm where everyone are equal.